# Error on App.contracts.TodoList = TruffleContract(todoList)

Tags: truffle

Working on Windows 10 Environment

Error from web server on windows 10:

'''

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

    app.js:56 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: TruffleContract is not defined

    at Object.loadContract (app.js:56)

    at async Object.load (app.js:8)
```

'''

Code referenced in error:

```
'''
      loadContract: async () => {
        //var contract = require("truffle-contract");
        // Create a JavaScript version of the smart contract
        const todoList = await $.getJSON('vote.json')
        console.log(todoList)
        App.contracts.TodoList = TruffleContract(todoList)
        App.contracts.TodoList.setProvider(App.web3Provider)

        // Hydrate the smart contract with values from the blockchain
        App.todoList = await App.contracts.TodoList.deployed()
      },
'''
```

Comment: It's great that you followed up with your solution, but if you solved your problem, it's best to add your solution as an answer to your question instead of just adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved added `var contract = required("truffle-contract");`